# Suggested format for SQL statement

Tags: sql, code-formatting

I've always struggled with how to format SQL queries in terms of whitespace, alignment, etc. It seems whenever there is an "auto-formatter" it seems to format things differently than the next one, whether it is within a SQL client or a website or text-editor that does various language formatting. Are there any guideline(s) for how SQL should be formatted for best readability? Here is an example of how I currently do it:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM 
    sales_instance si 
    JOIN main_iteminstance i ON si.instance_id=i.id
ORDER BY
    name
```

Also, yes I know this may be 'opinion-based' and people may want to close it for that, but I think this answer is helpful as to writing clean SQL and hopefully someone can provide a good summary of the available formats or guidelines.

Comment: [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c32f82ae18dce130dc7f8498b9b01455) is how I like to do it :)